# Why can I assign NULL to a pointer in my main function, but with the exact same code not in a other function?

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-behavior, dereference, null-pointer

I am fairly new to C and wanted to create a linked list.
For the list-elements I created a structure and wanted to initialize the head element in a function. The last element of the list shall contain a null-pointer so I know, when I reached the end. But if I initialize `next` to NULL inside the function, I get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

I tried to Google this, but I didn't find an answer.
After that I put the code from the function into my main and it worked. But why? It is the exact same code.

Inside function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list_node
{
    unsigned long value;
    struct list_node *next;
};

void new_list()
{
    struct list_node *cache;
    cache->next = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    new_list();

    return 0;
}
```

Inside main:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list_node
{
    unsigned long value;
    struct list_node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct list_node *cache;
    cache->next = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. And welcome to the world of undefined behaviour! Your code is illegal in both cases. You are accessing uninitialized pointers.

Comment: Thank you very much, the link was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared a an uninitialized pointer that has an indeterminate value.

```
void new_list()
{
    struct list_node *cache;
    cache->next = NULL;
}
```

So dereferencing the pointer

```
    cache->next = NULL;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

The same problem exists in the second program

```
int main()
{
    struct list_node *cache;
    cache->next = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

That is the second program also has undefined behavior.

What you should do is just write

```
int main()
{
    struct list_node *cache = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

That is initially your list is empty. So initially neither object of the type `struct list_node` was allocated and the pointer `cache` is equal to `NULL`.